# How did these characters in A Quiet Place 2 not notice the monster on board?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-quiet-place, a-quiet-place-2

In *A Quiet Place 2*, a monster sneaks in on the boat and attacks the island that was previously monster-free. But how did it get there? Did it just sneak into the boat and went unnoticed? Or is the implication that it stuck to the boat underwater as it was sailing?

Previously the monsters were always shown to have zero subtlety and immediately attacking everyone nearby, so it was unclear how that monster made its way across the water.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It's a different boat from the same dock

At the end of the fight against the gang on the dock, more than one boat is set free to float, not just the boat that Regan and Emmet escape on.

We see a monster end up on one of the other boats.  This boat just drifts to the island overnight.  It may have only just landed when Emmet discovered it.

Comment: At the time I thought - there's no way they showed us that monster ending up on the boat, and it doesn't end up on the island.

Comment: Major Chekhov's gun

Comment: Agreed @Carson - almost as big a Checkhov's gun as the nail from the first movie

Comment: Insane example of Diabolus ex Machina. Like... what is the chance of a boat floating to the island all on its own. Accepting.